# if else comparing two variables php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I'm current'y having 2 variables, for `$arrAns`, it contains the different answer that the user select for a checkbox. Example for $arrAns will be 1,2,3. And for `$arr`, it's the option variable which contains all the options that the question have. Example of `$arr` will be 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Here's the code whereby I trying to compare, if $arrAns == $arr, then the checkbox input will be "checked". else, it will be leave as blank.

But when I tried using the codes, if user's selection is 1,2,3. It works. But if user selects 2,3,4 non of the options will be "checked". And if user selects 1,3,4 only option 1 will be "checked".

Is there something wrong with the logic in between? In need of help, Thank you!

```
<?php if ($arrAns[$i] == $arr) { 
 ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'qns' . $qID; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $arr; ?>" class="required" checked/> <?php echo $arr; ?><br/>
<?php } else { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'qns' . $qID; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $arr; ?>" class="required"/> <?php echo $arr; ?><br/>
    <?php
} ?>
```

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes don't pass data through forms. They are simply ignored. If a checkbox is checked, then it will pass an 1, otherwise the value will not be defined. You could verify if the variable is defined for every option ( if (isset(...)) ) and, if it exists, do the comparison.  Or use in_array() as people said below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of seeing if an element exists I think you want to check to see if it is in the array or results.

Change

```
  <?php if ($arrAns[$i] == $arr) {
```

to

```
  <?php if (in_array($arr, $arrAns)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an effective use of [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
in_array($arr, $arrAns)
```